# Error: TypeError: circle() takes no keyword arguments

Tags: python, pygame, geometry, typeerror

I'm trying to create a game which includes a circle needing to be added after clicking somewhere, the other lines of code works fine, it is just the line of code `pygame.draw.circle(win, white, (105-circle_radius/2, 105-circle_radius/2), radius=circle_radius)` that returns the error of:

> ```
> TypeError: circle() takes no keyword arguments
> ```

Code:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

white = (255, 255, 255)
player_details = []
circle_radius = 100
WIDTH = 500
HEIGHT = 500


win = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))

(irrelevant code here)

def insert_input(slot_num, marker):
    board[slot_num] = marker
    print(board)


def circle_placement(x, y):
    if (31 <= x <= 179) and (31 <= y <= 179):
        slot1 = 1
        if board[1] == " ":
            insert_input(slot1, player_details[1])
            pygame.draw.circle(win, white, (105-circle_radius/2, 105-circle_radius/2), radius=circle_radius
        if board[1] != " ":
            print("Turn passed for attempting to Cheat!")

(irrelevant code here)
```

I've tried other shapes and all work fine, it's just this that doesn't work and returns an error: TypeError: circle() takes no keyword arguments, I've tried to change 'circle_radius' to a number instead of the variable but that doesn't work and I've tried changing the colour and that doesn't work either.

I haven't found any answers from the internet, from what I have researched, and when I did, they did not work, so I am hoping to find answers here.

Comment: Please post the full error traceback.

Answer (score 2):

The *radius* argument of [`pygame.draw.circle()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.circle) is not a keyword argument (remove `radius=`):

<s>`pygame.draw.circle(win, white, (105-circle_radius/2, 105-circle_radius/2), radius=circle_radius)`</s>

```py
pygame.draw.circle(win, white, (105-circle_radius/2, 105-circle_radius/2), circle_radius)
```